# Why is there now a difference between "{static const char a[]={...}" and "{const char a[]={...}"?

Tags: c++, c

Have a look at this tiny snippet of [C code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6c4QLO) or [C++ code](https://godbolt.org/z/JovbfB) on godbolt...

```
void b( char const *c);

void a(void)
{
   char const z[] = {0xd, 0xe, 0xa, 0xd, 0xb, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xa};

   b(z);
}

void c(void)
{
   static char const z[] = {0xd, 0xe, 0xa, 0xd, 0xb, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf, 0xa};

   b(z);
}
```

Earlier versions of gcc compiles both a() and c() to two instructions, load address of z, jump to b.

All modern compilers I tried "pessimise" a() to "make stack frame, copy z onto stack, call b, tear down stack frame, but leave c() as the two instruction simple version.

In effect nothing has changed, in practice modern compilers are now slower for this use case.....

Anybody have any idea why?

Comment: Note: `c()`'s `b(z)` passes a pointer to an array that is valid long after `b()` is complete.  Not so with `a()`'s `b(z)`.  Curious, does adding `restrict` to `void b(char const * restrict c);` change things?

Comment: Nope. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cB5-w7

Comment: `static char const z[]`，means `z` is static. Static variable must be in data section. So compiler will use two instructions. For `char const z[]`, z is const variable, I think compiler can put it in data section or just in stack. I think that's just compiler's choice, but not really sure about this. If use `char z[]`, then compile will put z just in stack, then function a will have more instructions.

Comment: The interesting thing is gcc used to make the choice just to leave it in the data section.... and then changed to make it slower. Furthermore all other recent compilers I tried on godbolt also use the slower version. This suggests there is a Good Reason.... Alas, I can't think what it is.

Comment: I saw you have use compile option '-Os'。 I try clang compiler with compiler options '-std=c99'. With different clang version the instructions is different but seems they all put array z in data section. [clang with std](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WEI4jk)

Comment: -std=c99 merely asks the compiler to use the c99 standard. -Os optimizes for small code size. It is the same as -O2 but with any optimizations that bloat the output removed. https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/s4xT3K

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C++ has the following [rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#9):

> Unless an object is a bit-field or a subobject of zero size, the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies. **Two objects with overlapping lifetimes** that are not bit-fields may have the same address if one is nested within the other, or if at least one is a subobject of zero size and they are of different types; otherwise, they **have distinct addresses and occupy disjoint bytes of storage**.

Now, check out this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void c();

void b(const char *a) {
    static const char *p = 0;

    if (!p) {
        p = a;
        c();
    } else {
        if (a==p) {
            printf("problem!\n");
        }
    }
}

void c() {
    const char a[] = { 0xd, 0xe, 0xa, 0xd, 0xb, 0xe, 0xe, 0xf };

    b(a);
}

int main() {
    c();
}
```

Here, `c` is called recursively once, so according to the rule, the array `a` should have different addresses in each recursion level. `b` stores `a` at the first invocation, and at the second invocation, it checks whether it is the same or not. With a conforming compiler, it should not print "problem!". But actually, with an old compiler (GCC 4.1, clang 6.0), it prints "problem!", so these compilers violate the standard.

A compiler is allowed to make `a` static only in the case that it can be proven that this change is not [observable](http://eel.is/c++draft/full#footnote-31):

> Under the “as-if” rule an implementation is allowed to store two objects at the same machine address or not store an object at all if the program cannot observe the difference

Comment: I can only upvote once, but this is essentially the same example `b` function I thought of, and a nice explanation balancing accessible and technically correct.

Comment: The C Standard isn't quite as explicit about this, but I think the same requirement is implied by 6.2.4/6 (non-VLA) and 6.2.4/7 (VLA) "If the [block/scope] is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time."

Comment: Well, you might want to mention the one exception: All string-literals may share space regardless.

Comment: @Deduplicator any given string literal is one static object. Whether multiple string literals with the same value are distinct objects is unspecified

Comment: @Caleth That would mean that if a string-literal is a proper suffix of another, they could not share space. There is no such restriction.

Answer (score 4):

I expect the answer to be that the compiler does what you in your code specify should happen - there must be a function-local array of automatic storage that is not shared with other threads, that is to be passed into other functions. Previously the compiler could use the as-if rule to remove that and put it elsewhere as the language didn't have threads as a thing that existed in its model, but since threads are now present it has to ensure it does not accidentally cause false sharing with others. It could've probably made it thread-local, but that's worse than just function local.

Note that GCC never did the optimization, but Clang stopped doing so after 6.0.0. It might even be a Clang bug to have used this optimization.

Comment: But the array is `const`, so there can't be a race condition.