# Is it possible to automatically define a variable static or non-static depending on whether the initialization is constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++17

Suppose that I have a type:

```
struct Foo {
    int a, b, c, d, e;
};
```

Now, I'd like to have a macro (or any other solution), which can define a `Foo` object in a way, that if the object can be `constexpr` (because it is initialized with compile-time `int`s), then it defines it as `static constexpr Foo`. If cannot be `constexpr`, then it defines as `const Foo` (I'd use this macro in function scope).

So, I'd like to have a macro (or some equivalent solution):

```
#define DEF(a, b, c, d, e) ... // magic here
```

If I call it with compile-time constants:

```
DEF(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Then I'd like this to expand to:

```
static constexpr Foo foo{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

But if any of the parameters are not compile-time constants (so it cannot be `constexpr`):

```
int b = 2;
DEF(1, b, 3, 4, 5); // second parameter is not a compile-time constant
```

then I'd like to have:

```
const Foo foo{1, b, 3, 4, 5};
```

The reason that I'd like to have something like this is that compilers are [not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53056597/why-is-there-now-a-difference-between-static-const-char-a-and-const) to optimize away `foo` from stack, so I have to do this optimization manually.

(Note, that I use `Foo` a lot of places, that's why I'd like to have an automatic solution. Currently I need to decide whether `foo` should be `static` or not case-by-case, which is tedious.)

Comment: There's no such _magic_ available with a macro. Use a template may be.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: that would be even better :) I've just used a macro, because it was easier to explain, and I thought that if this can be done at all, then it would be a macro based solution.

Comment: Try `__builtin_constant_p`?

Comment: It's worth noting that C++20 will have `std::is_constant_evaluated()`, which might allow for something like this.

Comment: @PasserBy: unfortunately, that builtin cannot be used for this purpose, because its return value is not whether the expression is a compile-time constant. And it is not portable either.

Comment: @Frank: thanks for the information! I've checked this out, but I'm not sure how I could use this function to solve my problem. As I understand, this function gives whether a `constexpr` function is evaluated in a constexpr context, or not. Here, I'd need to check whether an expression is constexpr or not. But I'll think about it.

Comment: why not creating a constexpr factory? if the input are const you get the constness, if not the variable. isn't that the expected behaviour for constexpr functions?

Comment: _"Currently I need to decide whether foo should be static or not case-by-case, which is tedious"_ Is it though? What's so complex about your initialisers that you don't intuitively know? Why can't you just write `constexpr` and see whether it compiles?

Comment: @OznOg: I don't quite follow you. Can you elaborate a little bit more on this?

Comment: @OznOg The issue is not about `constexpr`/`const`, it's about `static`/non-`static`, which behave differently at the code-gen when passing a pointer to them to a function because of the instance unicity guarantee requirements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: because I like automatize things which can be automatized. I use this `Foo` quite often. I don't want to check every single time whether it compiles with constexpr or not. After every code edit which uses `Foo`. I'm currently doing this, and it is tedious. And, an automatic solution won't make errors. It is highly likely that I have made some errors (mean perfomance degradation - not a serious one, of course) here and there.

Comment: You're just going to obfuscate your code for nothing

Comment: You're of course welcome to do whatever you like, but FWIW whatever your solution ends up being probably wouldn't pass code review by me

Answer (score 5):

I know you mentionned in the comments that `__builtin_constant_p` is not ok for you as you want a portable solution, but in case someone else stumbles upon this question, it can definitely be used to achieve this:

By combining `decltype(auto)`, automatic lambda capture and temporary lifetime extension, we can do the following:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

void worker(const Foo*);

#define DEF(A, B, C)                            \
  [&]() -> decltype(auto) {                     \
        constexpr bool test =                   \
          __builtin_constant_p(A) &&            \
          __builtin_constant_p(B) &&            \
          __builtin_constant_p(C);              \
                                                \
        if constexpr(test) {                    \
            static const Foo res {A, B, C};     \
            return (res);                       \
        }                                       \
        else {                                  \
            return Foo{A, B, C};                \
        }                                       \
    }()                                         \
    //end of macro

void foo(int v) {
    const Foo& x = DEF(1, 2, 3);
    //const Foo& x = DEF(1, v, 3);

    worker(&x);
}
```

Which generates the correct code in both scenarios. See on [godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/EDawR0)

If someone could come up with some crafty SFINAE sheananigans to replace `__builtin_constant_p` with something portable in this context, you would be in business.

**Explanation**: The real key here is the temporary lifetime extension. The reasoning is that having a macro spit out the static keyword would be a massive headache, so let's just not bother with it!

A `const Foo&` is perfectly capable of pointing to a `static const`, and as long as the regular `Foo` is built as a temporary, lifetime extension will (for every intent and purpose) promote the reference into a regular variable during compilation. Also, remember that **references do not have addresses of their own**, so the problem explained in your linked question does not apply to them.

With `decltype(auto)`, we can then create a function that can return either a temporary `Foo` or a `const Foo&` that will populate that `const` reference.

Finally, packaging this in a lambda (as opposed to helper functions/templates) allows us to easily distinguish literals versus named variables, and allows the compiler to establish for certain that the static variable gets initialized using constants expressions. This is important because a bunch of thread-safety boilerplate will get tacked on at the slightest hint of ambiguity.

Comment: You might want to remove the last semicolon from the macro so there isn't an empty statement where you use it.

Comment: You can replace `force_ref` with simply `return (res)` :)

Comment: @Quentin Learn something new every day!

Comment: @Frank: if I'm not mistaken, this is the same trick that we use with `decltype`. `decltype(a)` will get the actual type of `a`, `decltype((a))` will get a reference.

Comment: @Frank: btw, the problem with `__builtin_constant_p` is not just that it is not portable. It actually mean a different thing than compile-time constant. For example, for `int a = 42; __builtin_constant_p(a);`, GCC gives true (but only in the case if optimization is enabled).

Comment: @geza. Hmmm, that is indeed unfortunate. Poking around my code, it seems that it does not exhibit that behavior when mediated through a lambda capture, (which makes sense because the compiler does not know when the lambda will get invoked, and hasn't seen the code beyond the lambda yet), but I don't know if I'd want to rely on that.

Comment: @geza, also, if you interpret `__builtin_constant_p()` as "guaranteed to always have the same value (which I know right now)", I think having a static data const might still be the right choice in these cases might be what you want.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not the case. Thanks for thinking about this, though :) For example, if I use a function parameter to initialize `Foo`, and this function is called two times with different (but constant) parameters, I'll end up with only one static `foo`, it will be initialized with the first call. At least, if I'm not mistaken somewhere about this...

Comment: @geza, I believe you are indeed wrong. If the function parameter's value is known at compile time, then you are necessarily in the process of inlining the function, so the context would be specific to that call site, and not shared with anything else.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misunderstand you... There is only one static variable, even in the case when the inline function inlined into two different places.